# HZ typesetting system in plain TeX

Tags: spacing, macros, horizontal-alignment, formatting

How can I use the [hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hz-program) typesetting engine with plain TeX and pdfTeX?

I read about it in [TUG Vol 36 no.2, Peter Karow](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113zapf-karow.pdf).

Comment: This is covered in the [`pdfTeX manual`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex) under section "7.3 Fonts".

Comment: Okay I read the pdfTeX manual sec. 7.3 as Sverre directed and it does answer my question. However, I am not expert enough to put it to practical use. I will try to experiment with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sverre Thank you for the pointer. It is too advanced for me.

Comment: An experimental implementation of hz for plain TeX is available at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/tex-extensions/clasen

Comment: I have not pursued it yet. I think it is over my head.

Comment: Have a look at [protcode.tex](ftp://ftp.cstug.cz/pub/local/cstug/thanh/pdftex/ext/protcode.tex)

Comment: @Sverre: The last manual seems to have it in section 8.3 Fonts. Is this something that is done/turned on automatically when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX or do I need to turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

An experimental implementation of hz for plain TeX is available at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/tex-extensions/clasen.

Comment: But a non-experimental implementation is available with pdftex.

Comment: Indeed; but some people prefer not to have to deal with the pdf format.

Comment: pdftex can also output dvi.

Comment: Ah, yes, I now see in the pdftex docs that the hz extensions can also be used for dvi output. Thanks for the reminder! So the remaining case for plain tex hz would be for use in a project like [KerTeX](http://www.kergis.com/kertex.html).

Comment: why would you prefer dvi ?

Comment: It is mostly system builders and hackers who may have that preference: Smaller libraries, no C++, easier output format to write tools for. The KerTeX project I linked to is an example.